How to increase Google Drive storage of service token?
I initially used a User Token to access various Google APIs (Sheets, Docs, Drive, etc.) in a Python backend script. However, I encountered an issue with the token expiring and needing to be refreshed manually every month.
To resolve this, I switched to a Service Account Token, which avoids the need for manual token refreshes. Unfortunately, I recently discovered that the service account is limited to 15GB of Google Drive storage (as confirmed by about.get), and it seems impossible to increase this storage limit.
What are my options to obtain more storage (similar to a regular user account) without the need for manual token refresh (like the service account, which remains active)?
I'm also using workspace by the way. Maybe the service token can delegate to a workspace user?
Thanks.

You cant increase the storage on a service account.   YOu can share a directory with the service account.   So create a directory on a standard account and then have the service account upload to that directory

no it doesnt work, the service account still owns the files even if on another storage and it counts as its own storage

make the owner of the account the owner of the file after its uploaded

Not possible with API to transfer such ownership (service token to user).

who says?  permissions.create

Currently Drive does not support changing the ownership for items which are owned by gmail.com accounts; it's supported for Workspace accounts.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228791253

thats weird my apps working fine.

I delegated the right behave of report@xxx.com to my service token then permissions.create to transwer ownership from the token to report@xxx.com and it throw this error: "Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to report@xxx.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner"
